# Is there a term for measuring error on a second prediction based on the first's?

Tags: decision-trees, boosting, scoring

I have created a dataset which contains six values per row which may be the target value. Two rows for example:

```
1   1   1   1   0   7742    8901    7505    8714    8263    -1  29748   9394    60
1   -1  1   0   0   5658    6817    5420    -1  6178    7309    31833   6630    65
```

Where columns 6 through 11 of the 14 may be the target with its value shifted into the target column and its value replaced with -1.

The aim of this isn't to generate a great all round model but a model which when it makes a prediction it's maximum error is within a (beyond a reasonable doubt) range, not probably accurate.

I figure the approach to this is to skip initial prediction error and make a set of secondary predictions where it is assumed the initial predictions are accurate. The second set of predictions is then compared to the known value and only if its error is within a certain amount, in my case 0.03%, then track the absolute maximum error.

The final error reported in the absolute maximum error from the second round of predictions without ever questioning the quality of the initial predictions directly.

The end result so far has been models which where an initial prediction becomes the target and the second prediction results in an error of less than 0.03% then the first prediction has an absolute error of less than 3%. Roughly 10% of records survive.

Is there a term that describes this process?

Thanks